# My python twisted irc bot responding to commands

Tags: python, command, twisted, irc, bots

Hello People I'm building an irc bot using python twisted, everything is built but the bot doesn't respond to commands like i want it to. For example if i want to call a bot command on the irc channel i want to be able to call it like this $time and have the bot reply what time it is, i am able to get it to work like this -> crazybot $time and it prints the time but i don't want to have to type the name every time...How do i get the the bot to run the commands without calling the name first ? 
Here is the update -> everything connects 
.......

```
def privmsg(self, user, channel, msg):
    user = user.split('!', 1)[0]

   if not msg.startswith('#'): # not a trigger command
        return # do nothing
    command, sep, rest = msg.lstrip('#').partition(' ')
    func = getattr(self, 'command_' + command, None)

def command_time(self, *args):
    return time.asctime()
```

....
When i type !time there is no error and no output ..

Comment: Are you starting off using an existing project? or did you write this from scratch?

Comment: http://sscce.org/ or you're not going to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify [`MyFirstIrcBot`](http://www.habnabit.org/twistedex.html):

Replace `!` by `$` in:

```
if not message.startswith('!'): # not a trigger command
   return # do nothing
command, sep, rest = message.lstrip('!').partition(' ')
```

Add:

```
from datetime import datetime

# ...
def command_time(self, rest):
    return  datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it still didn't work :( it's not giving any error messages though

Comment: @nprezident: [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9014630/edit) and post [a minimal complete example](http://sscce.org/) that shows the error as Jean-Paul Calderone asked.